# .NET Wizards Frameworks

Tags: c#, asp.net, frameworks, wizard

I'm aware that there is an [ASP.NET Wizards Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs0za4w6.aspx) however this is fairly basic and doesn't offer a whole lot of flexibility.

I was wondering if there was a .Net based wizards framework that allowed you to build complex wizards with some of the following features:

- Re-use steps between wizards
- Dynamically control the wizard flow
- Per page and wizard wide validation

I know there are workflow / BPM style systems like Skelta and BPM, but I'm looking to build things like Line of Credit application or a Mortgage application which needs multiple steps and could have complex validation rules.

Answer (score 0):

You can do all three of your bullet points with the ASP.Net Wizard Control

1. Use Web Controls for the content of your steps.
2. On a click of the NextButton, capture what the ActiveStepIndex is and continue processing based on the result.
3. See #2.  You could, for example, call a validation function based on the step the user is currently on and control flow from step -to-step based on the result.